# Is there concurrent mutable Array(or any other indexed random access) in Scala/Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, scala, concurrency, thread-safety

I want to store count of integers in the corresponding indexes. Be able to update counts in parallel.
I've found java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicIntegerArray but it's impossible to get underlying array through API( I want to map over this array in the end)

Comment: What do you mean, "underlying array"?

Comment: @LouisWasserman AtomicIntegerArray is only an interface to underlying one ( private final int[] array; )

Comment: Yes, but it accesses it using special magic; you couldn't access the underlying `int[]` without destroying the concurrency.  You need to use its `get` and `length` methods to access it.

Comment: @LouisWasserman of course I can't, and there is no point doing so. But what was my aim is to perform some concurrent computations with AtomicIntegerArray and only after these computations be able to collect result for further calculations( count, filter and e.t.c because there is no such an API in the AtomicIntegerArray).

Answer (score 4):

Since the `AtomicIntegerArray` supports `length` method we can iterate over it  as shown below. (using scala)

```
(0 to atomicIntegerArray.length()-1)
   .map(atomicIntegerArray.get)
   .map( x =>  /*your map logic*/ )
```

Comment: Thank you! It's a simple and great workaround! But anyway it's somewhat strange that there is a lack of data structures similar to AtomicIntegerArray( indexed and with concurrent access for updating). Maybe somebody knows other classes?